# Monitor bvh file for changes in Motion Builder (Autodesk)

Tags: animation, file-monitoring, motionbuilder

Anyone with the MotionBuilder experience,

I want to update bvh file externally (adding motion data into it) and play the result in MotionBuilder. The program has Python scripts, one of which is FileMonitoring.py that is supposed to track changes in a file.

Is it possible to apply FileMonitoring.py script to .bvh file that specifies behaviour of the character?

So far I have tried applying the FileMonitoring to the .bvh file and updating the bvh file externally, but the motion is not updated.